# BackgroundWorker updating GUI without ProgressChanged in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a programm (WPF) which performs measurements every, lets say, 10 seconds. The measurement time varies, so it could take 1 second or maybe 3 seconds, e.g.:

```
|o........|..o......|o........|...o.....|o..

|...measurement start   o...measurement finished
```

I want to have a ProgressBar, which shows when the next measurement task starts. 
Also, everytime a measurement is finished, i add the values to a graph element to display them.

Now here is the Problem: I have a BackgroundWorker which checks if its time to perform a measurement. If its time, the BackgroundWorker starts other Workers which perform the measurement.

Right now i have just implemented the function to show the data when the measurement is completed using the "bw.ReportProgress(0)" (the 0 is a dummy value with no use):

```
private void measure_interval_worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        DateTime timeToMeasure = DateTime.Now; 
        Boolean varsSaved = true; //if vars are saved

        while (!measure_interval_worker.CancellationPending)
        {                

            if (activeDevices.Count == 0 && varsSaved == false) //Devives are finished and vars aren't save yet
            {
                bw.ReportProgress(0); //In ProgressChanged the values are displayed
                varsSaved = true;
            }

            if (DateTime.Now >= timeToMeasure && activeDevices.Count == 0) //If its time to measure and all devices are done with measurement
            {
                timeToMeasure = DateTime.Now + measure_gap; //Next time to measure
                measure_workers = new List<BackgroundWorker>(); //Deleting the "old" workers?


                foreach (var dev in devices)
                {
                    //Add Key
                    varsSaved = false;
                    activeDevices.Add(dev.Key);

                    //And start worker
                    measure_workers.Add(new BackgroundWorker());
                    measure_workers[measure_workers.Count - 1].DoWork += measure_perform_DoWork;
                    measure_workers[measure_workers.Count - 1].RunWorkerAsync(dev.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

activeDevices is just a list where the measure_workers delete their names if they are done so a activeDevices.Count == 0 means that all measurement tasks are done.

I tried to use a dispatcher now for the progressbar like:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                pbProgress.Value = (int)((timeToMeasure - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds/ measure_gap.TotalSeconds * 100);
            });
```

(placed it inside the measure_interval_worker while loop) but now if i start the measure_interval_worker the GUI freezes.

So how can i solve this?

I could use the ReportProgress for the ProgressBar but then i had the same problem for displaying the data because i dont know when the values are ready to display.

Comment: Press "Stop" in your debugger and analyse callstacks where your program blocks your GUI. Is the whole program deadlocked?

Comment: In the current form there is no assurance measure_workers are complete.  And I agree with other comments don't use BackgroundWorker in the BackgroundWorker.   I would use a BlockingCollection inside.  And if CancellationPending I would set e.Cancel = true;

Answer (score 1):

`activeDevices` is most probably not thread-safe. If it is a `List<T>` it's surely not. Use a ConcurrentBag, for example.

Furthermore, you shouldn't create a `BackgroundWorker` from another backgroundworker's `DoWork` method. It will not work as expected (because it's not created from the GUI thread).

Comment: what problems could occure using a backgroundworker inside a backgroundworker (the second backgroundworker has nothing to do with the ui, it just gets the measuredata and stores it into a class)

Comment: The `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events run in the thread that created the `BackgroundWorker` (if that thread supports this, which the WPF-GUI thread does). This is what the `BackgroundWorker` is actually for and it would be confusing otherwise. Nevertheless this should not be your problem, but I felt it would be useful to point that out.

Comment: i'm thankful for any advice, so the reason why background workers are used is that they have `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` mainly? And this events are running in the thread which created the worker (in most cases the ui thread)? So it would be better to use a `Task` like Sheridan said? I also looked at the ConcurrentBag, although i cant see any advantage in my special case using the bag

Comment: Yes - Task or ThreadPool directly. The ConcurrentBag is a thread-safe collection. I guess (what you omitted) that each thread removes "its" device vom activeDevices. If threads share ressource (activeDevices) they must synchronize access.

Comment: So if two workers wants to remove their "name" out of the `List<T>` at exactlly the same time, an error occurs? is this the problem?

Comment: You can't really know what may happen. It's a race condition. It's not only a problem if two threads remove their ID, but also if one thread removes itself and the other wants to know whether the list is empty or not. You *must* make sure, that no race condition occurs. Only then you could look for other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The `BackgroundWorker` is a quick and easy way to use multi-threading in .NET, but it might *not* be the best candidate in your scenario. Anytime you want something more than the `BackgroundWorker` class offers, then you'll need to look into using either the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in .NET 4.0, or the new [`async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx) and [`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) keywords in .NET 4.5.

Using these classes, you will be able to run *all* of your measurements together and have the UI update their progress asynchronously. You can find out how to use them in the following pages on MSDN:

[Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155756.aspx)
[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)